# How is the memory allocated to a variable if another (same data-type) variable is freed just before it?

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-management, stack, dangling-pointer

I saw this piece of c++ code under the topic of dangling pointer on the internet and tried executing it. 
This might not be pleasant to look at but here goes...

```
int *x, *y, *z;
x = new int;
*x = 3;
y = x;
delete x;
x = NULL;
z = new int;
*z = 5;
*y = 2;
```

When I print ***z**, it always turns out to be equal to the value of *y(as specified in the last line of code), 2 in this case but how is this possible if I specifically did ***z = 5** in the second last line itself.

Comment: Likely because `y` happens to be pointing to the same memory location. This is UB however, so `y` pointing to the same memory location as `z` is not guaranteed.

Answer (score 0):

With Undefined Behaviour, [everything is possible](http://catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html).

In your case, object to which `y` is pointing is destroyed (it's a *dangling pointer*), and dereferencing `y` using `*y` is UB (even worse when you try to assign something there).

It seems that after `delete x`, compiler decided to assign the memory block to `z` in the `new` call, which is perfectly reasonable (but not guaranteed - absolutely any other free memory block would be also valid).
Since `y` happens to point to the very same block of memory, it looks like you can manipulate `z` pointee object using `y`, but you cannot - you have no idea where `y` is really pointing.